# change D-Link Dir-615 router to DD-WRT?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, repeater

I have a `D-Link DIR-615` router (cheapest I can find) which supports DD-WRT, I did not install the latest build, because I heard it can have problems with the repeating part.

I am trying to find a guide, or script to make my life easier to setup this router as a stand alone repeater, in my previous attempt, I had to give this up, and just set it up as a client, and use a third router to send a new signal... so 3 routers on my network total in this setting, not very efficient...

So I bought a new router now, and want to give it a try again. so does anyone have any experience in how to really get this going as "repeater mode" not "client mode"?

DD-WRT version V24SP2

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Wifi Planet`:

> DD-WRT Tutorial 5: Wireless Repeater
>
> http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3655041

some intro stuff at the beginning, etc, skip down a little ways, and it should show you how to use the V24 version of DD-WRT as a wireless repeater...it is a 3 page tutorial...written in 2007, but still *relevant*.

Comment: another Tutorial, I will take a look, see if this one still seem to do the trick. altho I am not sure if I do correct, but when doing a site survey, I choose join an existing network, dd-wrt says connection successfullu, but under status/wireless, it does not say any AP is connected, not sure if it should stay there but I tought so. anyway I will take a look tonight when I am infront of my computers again, thanks!